# Multiprocessing: How do sharedctypes (RawArray, RawValue) work internally, how do they compare to SharedMemory and related questions

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've been reading up on concurrence and SysV- and POSIX-style shared memory in general and on Python's multiprocessing package in particular. Now I've got a few questions where I my Google-fu hasn't gotten me anywhere so far:

**Q1** As far as I understand from [this issue in the Python bugtracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue35813), the recently introduced `multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory` uses POSIX named shared memory. When it comes to types like `RawArray` and `RawValue` defined in `multiprocessing.sharedctypes`, however, the Python docs leave much to be desired. How are they implemented internally?

**Q2** Is the only practical difference between, say, a `RawArray('B')` and an instance of `multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory` that the latter has a name and is also accessible from unrelated (possibly non-Python) processes? Is their performance comparable?

**Q3** How exactly are multiprocessing locks implemented in Python? Don't they also need to use some kind of shared memory? The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Semaphore) say:

> Note
>
> Some of this package’s functionality requires a functioning shared
> semaphore implementation on the host operating system. Without one,
> the multiprocessing.synchronize module will be disabled, and attempts
> to import it will result in an ImportError. See [bpo-3770](https://bugs.python.org/issue3770) for
> additional information.

(Note that `multiprocessing.Lock` actually originates from `multiprocessing.synchronize.Lock`.) Now according to the linked issue [bpo-3770](https://bugs.python.org/issue3770), `Lock` uses libc's `shm_open()` which creates a named semaphore. Is this similar to how `SharedMemory` works?

**Update:** According to the source code – in particular, these lines: [Link 1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a33f2c2bae759fc9d06e1c032fd2026135f2df45/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py#L54), [link 2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a33f2c2bae759fc9d06e1c032fd2026135f2df45/Lib/multiprocessing/heap.py#L69) (thank you, bnaecker!), – on non-Windows systems `RawArray` and `RawValue` are just implemented using a temporary file which (at least on Linux) is placed in a directory not backed by storage, namely `/dev/shm`. This then seems very similar to how POSIX shared storage, i.e. `SharedMemory` works. So I guess I should replace my question Q1 with the following one: Why was `shared_memory` introduced in the first place then if `RawArray` is so similar? The aforementioned [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue35813) from the beginning mentions performance reasons but I don't understand where that performance difference (at least on Linux) is supposed to come from?

Comment: There are a _lot_ of questions here. I recommend breaking this down into small, self-contained questions, ideally with specific example code. You are much more likely to get answers that way.

Comment: For your first question about the implementation details, you could always [look at the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a33f2c2bae759fc9d06e1c032fd2026135f2df45/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py#L54).

Comment: @bnaecker You're right, I just removed some of my questions and might post them later.

Comment: @bnaecker As for your second comment: Thank you for the link! For some reason my IDE hadn't taken me to that code, so I figured it must be a built-in. Now that I've seen the code, I'll update my question accordingly.